# How to run parallel tests with AVA and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, testing, mongoose, mocking, ava

Based on the discussion for handling concurrency and atomic tests (https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/472)

I would like the best approach to test my server endpoints in parallel.

I'm using a koajs server and a mongodb database (mongoose)

I'm trying to use Mockgoose (https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose) to create a temporary in-memory mongod that will not persist the data

I wanna know if creating a separate database for each test is a good approach?

Is there any example of this?

Comment: Don't you get parallelism from Ava when writing tests in separate files?

Comment: we need a different database and server for each test to work without side effects in other tests

Comment: Ya, I don't see a problem in using a separate Mockgoose instance in the before handler of each test file.  It looks like Mockgoose automagically creates a DB when a connection is made?

Comment: take a look on this solution: https://github.com/Mockgoose/Mockgoose/issues/3#issuecomment-241894985

Comment: Did you try the `before` as opposed to `beforeEach`?  I guess I'm not sure why you can't initialize a mock database before the tests and run the tests in serial.  If you need to clean up the database for each test, you can do that in the `beforeEach`.  But your actual database connection and instance should be done once before all tests.  Use Ava's serial flag to ensure connections are not abused.

Comment: I wanna run in parallel not in serial, as described in the title of the question. Serial is working fine

Comment: I don't see a problem with creating a MongoDB instance for each test file as long as you have a convenient way to clean them up. I personally use MongoDB in a docker container that gets blown away when the tests are done running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not for AVA, but for Jest, you can use Jest [testEnvironment](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#testenvironment-string) setting to create a new environment which builds a mongodb database for each test, using the library [mongodb-memory-server](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server).

I've written about this with more details here: https://itnext.io/parallel-testing-a-graphql-server-with-jest-44e206f3e7d2

Answer (score 1):

Tricky. I made a module to handle this - https://github.com/cyberwombat/mongoprime

It works by using in memory mongo and creating a proxy. In your tests you will create a random database name and the module will take care of creating and loading/clearing these on demand databases for you.